# Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=#docid] unknown field '#fieldname'

Tags: solr, cloudera

I am new to Solr and just trying to index a couple of PDF files. Started with empty field list in schema.xml, I keep getting the error message:

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=#docid] unknown field '#fieldname'

(#docid and #fieldname are placeholders for real values here)

Is there a way how to find out all the fields in my PDF files? Adding one by another is just not too much fun :)

And what is the best way to filter these before being loaded to Solr? schema.xml seems to be the last option. Are there any config files, where I could get rid of the garbage fields
sooner, possibly improving performance?

My environment: Cloudera Quickstart VM with CDH 5

Thansk for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the [ExtractingRequestHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Configuration) (aka SolrCell) and it's configuration. There's an example there of how you can use `uprefix` to ignore all fields that are not known by the schema:

> Example: `uprefix=ignored_` would effectively ignore all unknown fields
>   generated by Tika given the example schema contains `<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored"/>`

There is also a list of fields defined in the example schema that lists all expected values from SolrCell and their types:

```xml
<!-- Common metadata fields, named specifically to match up with
     SolrCell metadata when parsing rich documents such as Word, PDF.
     Some fields are multiValued only because Tika currently may return
     multiple values for them. Some metadata is parsed from the documents,
     but there are some which come from the client context:
        "content_type": From the HTTP headers of incoming stream
        "resourcename": From SolrCell request param resource.name
-->
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="resourcename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<!-- Main body of document extracted by SolrCell.
     NOTE: This field is not indexed by default, since it is also copied to "text"
     using copyField below. This is to save space. Use this field for returning and
     highlighting document content. Use the "text" field to search the content. -->
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the meantime I got a solution which is fine for me using: <dynamicField name="*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />    But   type="ignored"   is a good hint once I want to get rid of the fields I do not need, thanks.